# Using Cordova and Android Studio with emulator, event log keeps showing "Unable to open connection to: localhost/127.0.0.1:5037"

Tags: cordova, android-studio, android-emulator, adb

I'm writing my first mobile app, with Cordova 9.0.0 on Linux (opensuse), and using Android Studio 3.4.2 and its emulator.  Whenever I start AS, start an AVD (emulator), and run `cordova emulate android` to run the app in the emulator, the Event Log in AS shows a few  of these:

```
Unable to open connection to: localhost/127.0.0.1:5037, due to: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

The app is only the tiny sample app so far, that shows an image and "device ready" message.  There is no networking code in it.  When run directly from Android Studio, as a project rooted in `./platforms/android/`, it works.

I understand that from the viewpoint of the emulator, the host device's IP address is 10.0.2.2 , not 127.0.0.1 .  Is there a way to tell adb (?) to use 10.0.2.2 ?  Or is there another way to configure anything to get this setup to work?

I've read many related posts on this site regarding this error message, but haven't found a solution that works for my setup.  Note that according to https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html#dns , the emulator doesn't use the `/etc/hosts` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:  Upgrade `adb` to the latest version.  `adb` is part of the full Android SDK, or you can download just the latest `platform-tools` package from Google at https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-linux.zip

In my case, I installed the full Android Studio (including SDK), but the install process didn't update my `/usr/bin/adb` with the included (latest) version.